# nautilus show desktop file as normal file

Tags: unity, nautilus, .desktop

here is my desktop file. **nautilus show icon and name** i set in desktop file.

```
▶ cat gitauto.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Git Auto Push/Pull
Icon=github-color.svg
```

but if i add one line, "Exec=xxxxx/git.pl", **nautilus show it as normal file**, not show "github-color.svg" here.

i use 14.04, and i found only "Exec" line within [Desktop Entry] can occour this, quicklist items not effect. Is this a nautilus bug?

[put a screen-shot to introduce different between normal file and desktop file](http://imagebin.org/319747)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all executables files a `.desktop` file needs executable permissions too to be recocgized as a "trusted" starter. Only then Nautilus will also display it's icon.

```
chmod +x gitauto.desktop
```

Note that you **need** an `Exec=/path/to/binary_or_script` line for a valid `.desktop` file. Also note that once made executable you will no longer have a right-click context entry to edit a `.desktop` file.

Comment: executable permissions/path is not the point. perhaps my declaration is not so clear, so i had added a screenshot here.

Comment: @eexpress: Did you try to give your .desktop file executable permission? If yes, then check whether the path to your executable and also to your icon is correct (we need a **full path** here). In the example you posted above, both the `Exec=` line is missing, and the `Icon=` line does not point to a full path.

Comment: of course i use full path, but i do not want set executable permission, all my desktop is same eprmission as -rw-rw-r-- and works fine. for my point is let nautilus show desktop files as it does as before, eg 12.04.

Comment: @eexpress I want to stress that Takkat is right. If a .desktop file is not executable => no icon. That's how it is.

Comment: here is my screenshot http://imagebin.org/319747

Comment: i take a new screenshot here, http://imagebin.org/319756. i am ture all my desktop files are not excutable. some shows as desktop file with icon and name, for those 3 files not Exec line within [Desktop Entry]. if you use vim to edit one, you can immediately see the effect in nautilus.

Comment: @eexpress, not in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`, ran via Dash, but on your desktopthey *must* be executable to use by double click and to show the icon. Try it.

Comment: my god, chmod +x *.desktop, it really show icon and name now. but why those 3 files shows ok before i +x it?  i mess up. thanks all .

Comment: They must have been ex. already somehow. )